# How to declare types on Typescript for spread props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to figure out how to get this code to work on TypeScript

```
type ScrollProps = {
  autoHide: boolean
  autoHideTimeout: number
  autoHideDuration: number
}

const renderThumb = ({ style, ...props}) => {
  const thumbStyle = {
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(35, 49, 86, 0.8)'
  }
  return <div style={{ ...style, ...thumbStyle }} {...props} />
}

const CustomScrollbars = (props: ScrollProps) => (
  <Scrollbars
    renderThumbHorizontal={renderThumb}
    renderThumbVertical={renderThumb}
    {...props}
  />
)

...
<CustomScrollbars autoHide autoHideTimeout={500} autoHideDuration={200}>
 ...
</CustomScrollbars>
```

If I create a type for the props on CustomScrollbars I get an error on `<CustomScrollbars>`, if I don't I get an error on the props at the CustomScrollbars function.

I also get an error on `style`, it wants to know what type, but I do not know what type to put.

Why does the implicit `any` not work and how can I make this code to work on TypeScript?

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-with-typescript-forked-8g5g6

Comment: Please let me know what kind of error you get if you create the type for the props on CustomScrollabars

Comment: That got fixed by adding `children:  React.ReactNode` to the props, my problem now is with `style` current error for that is `Binding element 'style' implicitly has an 'any' type`

Comment: Declaring the component as `const CustomScrollbars : FC<ScrollProps>` should remove the need to explicitly declare the children prop. (Where `FC` is `React.FC`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add `children` into the props type.

And for style, add the following type

```
const renderThumb = ({ style, ...props}: {style: React.CSSProperties}) => {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that fixes the ScrollProps, by adding `children:  React.ReactNode`,  how about the `style`?

Comment: I can see only simple Hello project on it

Comment: Sorry my bad https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-with-typescript-forked-8g5g6

Comment: Thank you, it does not give any errors but for some reason it does not work, the original without TypeScript works https://codesandbox.io/s/p30737114j

Comment: You need to set height of Scrollbars using style.
<Scrollbars style={{height: 500}} ... />

Comment: Thank you, that fixed all the issues!

Answer (score 2):

In all honestly the types for the `react-custom-scrollbars` package are really lacking.  The expected type for the `renderThumbHorizontal` and `renderThumbVertical` props is declared as `React.StatelessComponent<any>` -- a component that takes `any` props.  So I have no idea if the props that those components will be called with match the props that your `renderThumb` is expecting.

As far as declaring the props for `renderThumb` (which I recommend capitalizing, as is will create problems if you try to use it in JSX like `<renderThumb />`), the spread operator doesn't really matter.  You are accepting an object of props and all of them are passed down to a `div`.  So we want to accept whatever props a `div` would accept.  That type is `JSX.IntrinsicElements['div']`.

With this definition, `style` is type  `React.CSSProperties | undefined`.  It's actually ok to spread `undefined`, so you don't need to require `style` or set a default.

```
const RenderThumb = ({ style, ...props}: JSX.IntrinsicElements['div']) => {
  const thumbStyle = {
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(35, 49, 86, 0.8)'
  }
  return <div style={{ ...style, ...thumbStyle }} {...props} />
}
```

As far as the `CustomScrollbars`, you can import the props from the package rather than having to redefine them yourself.  If you type the component as `React.FunctionComponent<Props>` that will include the `children` prop automatically. (But something is wonky with your CodeSandbox because it can't find that type).

```
import React from "react";
import { Scrollbars, ScrollbarProps } from "react-custom-scrollbars";

const CustomScrollbars: React.FC<ScrollbarProps> = (props) => (
  <Scrollbars
    renderThumbHorizontal={renderThumb}
    renderThumbVertical={renderThumb}
    {...props}
  />
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a really good explanation. I tried it and it works perfectly